# IntelliJ JavaFX build artifact with packaged maven dependencies

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javafx

I am trying to distribute a JavaFX jar file containing alle maven dependencies. However my only builds which are working, have the maven dependencies extracted as .jar files.

[image: Output directory]

[image: Artifact]

My pom file contains following lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>groupId</groupId>
<artifactId>MusikPlayer</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.38</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaudiotagger</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Is there any way to distribute the JavaFX jar file with all maven dependencies within, sothat i only have 1 jar file?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the [`javafx-maven-plugin`](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>8.4.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>your.package.with.Launcher</mainClass>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

With `your.package.with.Launcher` being you `Application` class. This plugin also allows you to create native bundles. For ease of use take a look at their [page](http://javafx-maven-plugin.github.io/) to quickly pull together the plugin configuration for the most common cases.

With the above configuration you can build the all in one executable jar file with `mvn jfx:jar`. The jar file will be located in `target/jfx/app`.

Comment: According to their site: "This is where the base executable JavaFX jar is built into, along with any dependent libraries (place in the 'lib' sub-directory)." This is exactly what i try to avoid!

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest upgrading to openJFX. I see you're using JavaFX bundled in JDK 1.8. Please consider doing that below as it will not only do what you're looking for (which is compiling your project into a jar), but also will improve your application with the new JavaFX functionalities, improved performance, fixed bugs, etc.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
            <classifier>win</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
            <classifier>win</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
            <classifier>win</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
            <classifier>win</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
            <classifier>win</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
            <classifier>win</classifier>
        </dependency>
```

Replace

> 11

Where it is notated as

```
${javafx.version}
```

Inside build>plugins:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.8</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>${javafx.mainClass}</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Replace

```
${javafx.mainClass}
```

With your main class which extends Application and has a main method. Note that it has to be a full qualified name, example:

```
com.app.Main
```

After pasting all of it, just go to terminal and run

```
mvn clean install
```

Your runnable jar will be inside target folder (which is auto-generated by maven).

To run your jar simply double-click on it or run with

```
java -jar "your_jar_name.jar"
```

Note that you don't have to remove anything from your pom.

Hope that helps!